# Show that minimum of $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ subject to constraint $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = 1$ is $1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Using Lagrange multipliers, I can see that the *maximum* of $f(x, y, z)$ subject to the constraint is $\sqrt{3}$.

To see this, here is what I did:

- Show the constraint in the form $g(x,y,z) = k$, which gives us $g(x, y, z) = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - 1$.
- To satisfy $\nabla{f(x, y, z)} = \lambda \nabla{g(x, y, z)}$, start by taking all the relevant partial derivatives:

  - $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x$
  - $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y$
  - $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 2z$
  - $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 4x^3$
  - $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 4y^3$
  - $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = 4z^3$

3. Set up a system of equations, and solve.

   - $2x = \lambda4x^3$
   - $2y = \lambda4y^3$
   - $2z = \lambda4z^3$
   - $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = 1$
4. Skipping ahead through the remaining arithmetic, this gives $x^2 = y^2 = z^2$ and also $x = y = z = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$.

   To see this in more detail, we can use $g(x, y, z)$.  If $x^2 = y^2 = z^2$ as we stated, then we have:

   - $(x^2)^2 + (y^2)^2 + (z^2)^2 = 1$

   and therefore

   - $(x^2)^2 + (x^2)^2 + (x^2)^2 = 1$, etc.).

   Plug this into $f(x, y,  z)$ to get $\sqrt{3}$, which is the maximum of the function subject to the constraint.

However, the answer key in my textbook says that the *minimum* is $1$.  Can someone explain why the minimum is $1$, and how to understand that?

Comment: Please include your calculations.

Comment: $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 \ge x^4 + y^4 + z^4 =1$ with equality happening for two of the variables to be zero

Comment: You divided by $x$, $y$, and $z$  when the variable(s) in question could be zero. I'd suggest correcting by including the possibility where the variable(s) are zero in your calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, all...I edited to include my work.  Happy to include even more arithmetic/steps if it helps.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for pointing that out @Zarrax!  Could I trouble you to explain further though why the variables $x,y,z$ could be zero?  If they are zero, then...doesn't that leave $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = 1$ unsatisfied?  (maybe I am jumping ahead somehow).  I'm also assuming that $x = y = z$...maybe I shouldn't be assuming that?

Comment: Step 4, "skipping through the remaining arithmetic..." is wrong. It is not required that $x=y=z$. There are other solutions, e.g
$$x=2^{-1/2}=y~~,~~z=0$$
Or, $x=1~~,~~y=z=0$, which is a minimum.

Comment: Ah, ok!!  Thank you for explaining that and giving an example, that is very helpful.

Comment: **HINT** : The constraint $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$ means that the vectors $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel, I.E, their cross product is zero. See what happens when you calculate $\nabla f\times \nabla g$ and set it equal to zero. You will see there are many more solutions than $x=y=z$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, also!  Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x = 2\lambda x^3$

Either $x = 0$ or $\lambda =\frac {1}{2x}$.

You have investigated what happens if $\lambda = \frac 1{2x}$ but what about $x = 0?$

Comment: Gotcha...that makes sense along with the comments as well.  Thank you!